# .Net 2.0 List Issue

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, generic-list, generic-collections

Getting an error, hopefully that can be fixed.

I have a Strongly typed list (or at least I am attempting to use one rather...)  It only contains 2 properties... NodeName (string), NodeValue(string)

The error I am getting is when trying to add to said list:

```
_Results.Add(New Calculator01.ResultTyping() With {.NodeName = "Number_Departures_Per_Day", .NodeValue = DC_NDPD.ToString()})
```

Is producing the following error:

`error BC32017: Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.`

Yes, this is an inherited .Net 2.0 website, and no, I cannot upgrade it to a newer version.  (I asked the boss already)

I am open to using a different generic collection though, so long as I can strongly type it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Object Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) were introduced with Visual Studio 2008 so they were simply not available in .NET 2.

But you can use this syntax:

```
Dim calculator As New Calculator01()
calculator.NodeName = "Number_Departures_Per_Day"
calculator.NodeValue = DC_NDPD.ToString()
_Results.Add(calculator)
```

If you want one line you should provide an appropriate constructor which is a good thing in general:

```
Class Calculator01

    Public Sub New(NodeName As String, NodeValue As String)
        Me.NodeName = NodeName
        Me.NodeValue = NodeValue
    End Sub

    Public Property NodeName As String
    Public Property NodeValue As String

End Class
```

Now you can use this code:

```
_Results.Add(new Calculator01("Number_Departures_Per_Day", DC_NDPD.ToString()))
```